# explorer not following dropdown list option link under jquery

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu

1st new to this list. please pardon  any faux pas....

this is the html... (Q1..not sure of syntax for selected option but this seems to work...)

```
<select>
<option class=" " value="choose" selected="yes" SELECTED>choose language</option>
<option class=" turnoffbuttonenglish" value="japanese" >日本語 </option>
<option class=" turnoffbuttonjapanese" value="english" >English </option>
<option class="turnonboth" value="both" >both </option>
</select>
```

each option chooses which language to display in the page and an iframe.

here is the jquery that seems not to be working (I think the problem is here and not elsewhere in my code...)

there are analogous sections of code for the three options. but below is the exammple for class turnoffbuttonjapanese. (name is legacy, it really shows english..class hidden displays none...

```
 $('.turnoffbuttonjapanese').click( function() {
$currentLanguage ="2" 
$('.japanese').addClass("hidden"); 
$('.english').removeClass("hidden");
$currentIFrame.contents().find(".japanese").each(function(index, item) {
 $(item).addClass("hidden"); 
});
$currentIFrame.contents().find(".english").each(function(index, item) {
 $(item).removeClass("hidden"); 
});
});
```

This seems to work in opera, but not in explorer!!??? 
 when I select nothing happens.

If instead I have

```
   <div class=" english hidden turnoffbuttonenglish"> <a
  class=" turnoffenglish" title="see 日本語 page">日本語&nbsp;<img
  src="images/chopsticks150.png" height="100%" alt="chopsticks"> </a></div>

<div class=" japanese turnoffbuttonjapanese"><a
  class=" turnoffjapanese" title="see ENGLISH page">English&nbsp;<img
  src="images/knifeandfork150.png" height="100%" alt="knife and fork"></a>    </div>
```

this works...???

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question, are you able to post it on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting this. nick seems to have gotten what I was shooting for...must say I never heard of jsfiddle..looks interesting and will look into it more, but not worth it on this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of relying on the `click` event of an `<option>` (which won't work cross-browser as you're seeing), instead go by the value (and if possible, give that `<select>` an ID to make it cleaner), like this:

```
$('#mySelectID').change(function() {
  if($(this).val() == "english") {
    $currentLanguage = "2";
    $('.japanese').addClass("hidden"); 
    $('.english').removeClass("hidden");
    $currentIFrame.contents().find(".japanese").addClass("hidden");
    $currentIFrame.contents().find(".english").removeClass("hidden");
  }
});
```

The reason the first `<select>` version isn't working is because not all browsers even fire that `click` event on an `<option>`, so your code never gets to run.  Taking this approach will work and be more cross-browser stable.  If you want an immediate effect on browsers that don't fire `change` until `blur` occurs, you can run it a bit more often using [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), just replace [`.change(function() {`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) with [`.bind('change click', function() {`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).

You can also re-work this a bit, not sure of your overall intentions, for example you can hide all of them, then show the value your selected, instead of an `if` for each option, making your code much shorter.

Comment: thanks soooooo much for the lucid explanation. I just didn't know about click not firing (seems crazy: I clicked, you fire!) but so hath the gods decreed...anyway your solution seems to be what I was looking for. Much obliged...give yourself a beer..
:-)

ps you are probably right about the rethink too...

Comment: @user383363 - Welcome :) Remember to accept an answer if it helps via the checkmark on the left, it'll help you get answers to future questions faster...also, welcome to SO!